# Bison parser not reporting error within case statement

Tags: compiler-errors, compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer

I am getting the following output of running a bison parser :
[Bison parser output on a file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANPg3.png)

In the above image i gave the **compile** executable generated using **bison** and provided the **syntax5.txt**.
If you see it caught the error when => 2; properly
it should be something like when 1 => 2;
But below it there is one more when which is also missing the literal. Its not picking that for some reason. And total number of errors should be 5 its showing as 4.

what could be the reason for this.
Here is the parser.y file that i am using. Its something to do with the way i have defined grammar.

```
%{

#include <string>

using namespace std;

#include "listing.h"

int yylex();
void yyerror(const char* message);

%}

%define parse.error verbose

%token IDENTIFIER
%token INT_LITERAL

%token ADDOP MULOP RELOP ANDOP
%token  IF BOOL_LITERAL ARROW EXPOP REMOP OROP NOTOP CASE 
%token ELSE ENDCASE ENDIF OTHERS REAL THEN WHEN REAL_LITERAL 

%token BEGIN_ BOOLEAN END ENDREDUCE FUNCTION INTEGER IS REDUCE RETURNS

%%

    
function:   
    function_header variable body ;
    
function_header:    
    FUNCTION IDENTIFIER RETURNS type ';' |
    FUNCTION IDENTIFIER parameters RETURNS type ';' |
    error ';';
    
variable:
    IDENTIFIER ':' type IS statement_  variable |
    ;
    
    
parameters: parameter |
            parameter ',' parameters |
;           

parameter: IDENTIFIER ':' type ;

type:
    INTEGER |
    REAL |
    BOOLEAN ;

body:
    BEGIN_ statement_ END ';' ;
    
statement_:
    statement ';' |
    error ';' ;

statement:
    REDUCE operator reductions ENDREDUCE |
    IF expression THEN statement_ ELSE statement_ ENDIF |
    expression |
    CASE expression IS when OTHERS ARROW statement_  ENDCASE 
    ;

when: WHEN INT_LITERAL ARROW expression ';'|
      when WHEN INT_LITERAL ARROW expression ';' |
      error ';'|
       ;

       
     
operator:
    ADDOP |
    MULOP ;

reductions:
    reductions statement_ |
    ;
          
expression:
    expression OROP expression2 |
    expression2;
    ;



expression2: 
     expression2 ANDOP expression3 |
      expression3;
      ;

expression3: NOTOP expression3 |
              expression4 
         ;
        
expression4: relation;
         
relation:   
    relation RELOP term |
    term;

term:
    term ADDOP factor |
    factor ;
 
factor:
    factor MULOP factor2 |
    factor REMOP factor2 |
    factor2;
    
factor2: 
       factor3 EXPOP factor2 |
       factor3 
       ;

factor3: primary;
      

primary:
    '(' expression ')' |
    INT_LITERAL | 
    BOOL_LITERAL |
    REAL_LITERAL |
    IDENTIFIER ;
    
%%

void yyerror(const char* message)
{
    appendError(SYNTAX, message);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])    
{
    firstLine();
    yyparse();
    lastLine();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The issue i am seeing is with the case statements only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bison, like yacc, suppresses error messages for the first three tokens after an error recovery. This avoids a cascade of errors resulting from imprecise recovery.

You can reenable error reporting using the `yyerrok` macro, but only in the context of an action. (So you can't use it in the definition of `yyerror`.) The parser action would typically be an error recovery action; that is, an action for a production which includes the `error` pseudo-token.

For more information and examples of how to write error recovery productions, see the [error recovery chapter of the bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Error-Recovery.html#Error-Recovery).

Comment: Also if you see not it only it's suppressing the next error in when statement

Comment: Also if you see not only it's suppressing the error in the when statement. But the case statement must have an others statement as mentioned in the grammar. It doesn't even output that.  If I make both when statements correct then it will throw error for missing others statement.

Comment: @ronitsharma: It suppresses errors for *three tokens*. That's often in the same statement, but not always.